# how to display the data in html file from type script in angular js 8

Tags: angular

I have made an API call which is GET method like this:

app.component.ts:

```
  export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
      usersdatainfo : any;
      constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { 

         this.http.get(this.url).subscribe( userdata => {
          this.usersdatainfo = userdata
          console.log(typeof this.usersdatainfo);
       });
     }
 }
```

when I print

```
console.log(typeof this.usersdatainfo);
```

I am getting output like :

```
 object
```

I want to add the data in Html table,

This is my Html Code:

```
          <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="userid">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header> User UID </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="User UID"> {{row.userid}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="firstname">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header> First Name </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="First Name" class="tab-data"> {{row.firstname}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="lastname">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header> Last Name </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="Last Name"> {{row.lastname}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header> User Name </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="User Name"> {{row.username}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
             <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row;></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
```

I want to display my API response inside table how can I do that

Comment: Make sure the response from the API has a proper structure that can be fed into table. And you are not binding data correctly. It should be like this, `[dataSource]="usersdatainfo"`

Answer (score 0):

Type `console.log(this.usersdatainfo)` for data.

Angular Mat table starts like `<table mat-table [dataSource]="usersdatainfo" class="mat-elevation-z8">`. I think rest of your code will work fine.